# MySQL Round & Sub-Queries

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with the round function when creating a temporary table. (Well I think that is the problem anyway)

The column "EntryGauge" in the list below needs to be scaled and rounded based on another value in the database (different table).

There are 2 queries which I thought I could use as sub-queries to retrieve the scale factor and rounding precision value. When I try to use them (as shown in the query below) this error appears:

> "SQL Error (1166): Incorrect column name 'ROUND(EntryGauge * (SELECT DisplayScaleFactor FROM webreportparametersetup WHERE MachineIdent = 'Mac'"

I'm not sure what the issue is, or if I'm using subqueries properly but I could really use some help!

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS LiveFeed;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LiveFeed AS
(
SELECT 
    MachineIdent, 
    CoilID, 
    DATE_FORMAT(StartTime, '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p'), 
    DATE_FORMAT(EndTime, '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p'), 
    TIMEDIFF(EndTime, StartTime), 
    Alloy,
    ROUND(EntryGauge * (SELECT DisplayScaleFactor FROM webreportparametersetup WHERE MachineIdent = 'MachineIdent' AND ItemName = 'EntryGauge'), (SELECT DisplayPrecision FROM webreportparametersetup WHERE MachineIdent = 'MachineIdent' AND ItemName = 'EntryGauge')), 
    ExitGauge, 
    EntryWidth, 
    ExitWidth, 
    CoilDiameter, 
    CoilLength 
FROM Coil 
    INNER JOIN CoilPass 
    ON Coil.CoilIdent=CoilPass.CoilIdent 
    INNER JOIN PassSection
    ON CoilPass.PassIdent=PassSection.PassIdent 
WHERE PassSection.SectionIdent IN('7965','7966','7967')
);
```

**Edit:** Just to be clear about what the calculation needs to look like:

> Round(EntryGauge * ScaleFactor, RoundingPrecision)

Comment: 1. Does the columns actually exists? 2. Try naming the column after usage. `ROUND(EntryGauge * (SELECT DisplayScaleFactor FROM webreportparametersetup WHERE MachineIdent = 'MachineIdent' AND ItemName = 'EntryGauge'), (SELECT DisplayPrecision FROM webreportparametersetup WHERE MachineIdent = 'MachineIdent' AND ItemName = 'EntryGauge')) AS EntryGagesRounded,`

Comment: Can you run the sub queries in the ROUND function separatley, just to confirm that they are correct?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the main issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just forgot to give the rounded column a name?
The Join gives you a better overview:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS LiveFeed;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LiveFeed AS
(
SELECT 
    MachineIdent, 
    CoilID, 
    DATE_FORMAT(StartTime, '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p'), 
    DATE_FORMAT(EndTime, '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p'), 
    TIMEDIFF(EndTime, StartTime), 
    Alloy,
    ROUND(EntryGauge * webreportparametersetup.DisplayScaleFactor,webreportparametersetup.DisplayPrecision) as RoundedValue, 
    ExitGauge, 
    EntryWidth, 
    ExitWidth, 
    CoilDiameter, 
    CoilLength 
FROM Coil 
    INNER JOIN CoilPass 
    ON Coil.CoilIdent=CoilPass.CoilIdent 
    INNER JOIN PassSection
    ON CoilPass.PassIdent=PassSection.PassIdent
    LEFT JOIN webreportparametersetup
    ON MachineIdent = 'MachineIdent' AND ItemName = 'EntryGauge'
WHERE PassSection.SectionIdent IN('7965','7966','7967')
);
```

Comment: Thanks! that fixed the main issue. I was just wondering though, in the part where I'm referencing MachineIdent (in the left join) Is there some sort of syntax to use whatever the current record being retrieved is? Sort of like MachineIdent = @MachineIdent? (Scale factors etc are on a "Machine Dependent" basis.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
ROUND(EntryGauge * (SELECT DisplayScaleFactor 
FROM webreportparametersetup WHERE MachineIdent = 'MachineIdent' 
AND ItemName = 'EntryGauge'),2), ROUND((SELECT DisplayPrecision 
FROM webreportparametersetup WHERE MachineIdent = 'MachineIdent' 
AND ItemName = 'EntryGauge'),2)
```

I think it's a problem with parentheses

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the Rounding Calc needs to be in this format: _Round(EntryGauge * ScaleFactor, RoundingPrecision)_ So the second sub-query needs to go where you put "2" in the round function, as it represents that number.